# Are edge states always topological?

Tags: topology

Hey am new to this forum but I have a question regarding topologically protected states.. Lets suppose we have a 1D gapped system divided two to distinct regions that have different periodicity or different properties and that at the centre, where the two regions 'meet' states appear in the gap. The simplest example where this happens is the SSH model. But i was wondering whether this is generally true. Are these states always topological?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

A simple example is given by the spin-$2$ Affleck-Kennedy-Lieb-Tasaki state/chain. For a while people thought this spin chain was topological, since it indeed has has degenerate edge modes with open boundary conditions, but we now know they are not protected and indeed there is no topological invariant associated to the system. More concretely, in ''[Symmetry protection of topological order in one-dimensional quantum spin systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4059)'' (Pollmann, Berg, Turner, Oshikawa, 2009) it was shown (in Fig 4) that one can adiabatically connect that spin chain to a trivial state, even without breaking spin rotation symmetry or any other symmetry that one might deem relevant.

Hence degenerate edge modes are not enough to label a chain as topological. A more secure way is by looking its entanglement spectrum when partitioning the chain in two halves. A topological chain will have degenerate entanglement values *everywhere* in the entanglement spectrum. I do not know of a single counter-example where a system has that property but is not topological. The above spin-$2$ chain, however, does have degenerate values at the bottom of the entanglement spectrum, but not higher up, consistent with it not being a (symmetry protected) topological phase of matter.

Comment: I've never heard this term before but I will look it up so thank you for your suggestion. I was wondering though, as I am more of an experimentalist, if such states exist in a system how can you differentiate the category they belong to? I am looking into micromagnetic systems that cannot/or are very hard to solve analytically.

Comment: @AnGGeL That is a very good question. Let me first say that I would expect in practice that if you find a system with edge modes, that it is probably topological. The point is that one can fine-tune models to have edge modes (such as the above spin-$2$ chain) but generic perturbations would destroy that behavior. Then on the more concrete question of identify phases of matter, measuring so-called string order parameters could be one route. There is in fact a recent experimental paper where they try to do this (although not in the context of topological phases): arxiv.org/abs/1702.00642

Comment: For a more detailed reply on how to experimentally detect both edge modes and identify distinct symmetry protected topological phases of matter, I would recommend posting that as a question on its own right.

Comment: Thank you! Am new to this topic and as an experimentalist I struggle with a lot of concepts used as the representation is too mathematical most of the times. I will make this post more specific but if you have any references about how to measure Zak phases or anything that would point me in the right direction i will be grateful! Another question I will ask (if you already know the answer please enlighten me) is how do you prove the robustness of such states. Thank you again for your prompt replies